# Implicit Declaration Of Function

Tags: c, linker, compiler-warnings, ld

I've just organized my code by using headers, but just as I've done this, I got a warning that turned into an error when linking.

I have a code(use of a function that is inside a header) in `test.c` that is like this:

```
#include "test1.h"

/* Some code */
main()
{
   Testing();
}
```

And my `test1.h` header is like this:

```
void Testing();
void print(int, int, int, const char*);
```

And at `test1.c`

```
void Testing()
{
   print(0xF9, 27, 5, "\xC9\\xBB");
}

void print(int colour, int x, int y, const char *string)
{
   volatile char *video=(volatile char*)0xB8000 + y*160 + x*2;
   while(*string != 0)
   {
      *video=*string;
      string++;
      video++;
      *video=colour;
      video++;
   }
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I got this:

> ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$ gcc -o test.o -c test.c -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
>   test.c: In function ‘main’:
>   test.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Testing’
>   ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$

At the time it's just a simple warning, but when I try to link it...

> ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$ ld -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin loader.o test.o
>   test.o: In function `main':
>
>   test.c:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to`Testing'

What I need to do?

Comment: The filename in your warning message doesn't match the example command you have shown.  So, it obviously isn't the code you're running.  We don't know what you're doing.  Post a complete example that we can compile.  Also, bad idea to define functions in header files.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I've just edited.

Comment: Test.h is referenced in the include not test1.h...same likewise for test1.c which is not in the gcc command line also....

Comment: Even after the edit, the compiler and linker still refer to the old file names. But in any case, even with the edited `main.c` some of the described symptoms are highly unlikely, if not impossible. You are either posting fake code, or fake error messages. Re-verify your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** To reflect the OP's question I have struck out some lines of my answer despite being upvoted...

<strike>Why is kernel.c flagged up in the compiler, even though you don't have it mentioned here? Am I missing something...</strike>

```
gcc -o test.o -c test.c -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
kernel.c: In function ‘main’:
kernel.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Testing’
ubuntu@eeepc:~/Development/Test$
```

maybe you need to do it this way somewhere in your header file as I'm judging you want kernel to access this function:

```
extern void Testing();
```

And, take out all your functions and place them in a separate .c file, they should not be in there in the first place... for example:

```
Testing.c
/* all your functions here */

Testing.h
/* Only global, external variables and function prototypes */
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: @t0mm13b: Excellent Answer, But still I would like to know what does "Implicit Declaration Of Function" line means?

Answer (score 1):

I can't recreate your problem. This works as expected when I try to compile your code on an Ubuntu machine (Which based on your paste, I assume you're using.)

Are you sure the #include is happening correctly?

Try using -E instead of -c to see what the whole code the compiler is trying to compile looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a shot in the dark here, since my C is a bit rusty, but does C allow you to put function bodies in a header? I don't recall that it does. Try moving the definition of Testing() and print() into a .c file? You could also try compiling as C++ as see if that fixes it, if you don't need/want C.

Comment: C doesn't distingusish between header and code files.

He's #included the .h into the .c, so there's no difference between that and directly putting it in the file.

Comment: Sure you can put active code in the header. It's just a bad, bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I do enough C++ that the differences between them blur sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You included `test.h` into `main.c`, while your declarations, according to what your wrote, are in `test1.h`. Note the `1` in the name.

In addition to that, you are compiling `test.c` and linking `test.o`, while in reality the name of your file is `test1.c`. Again, note the `1` in the name.

**Edit:** Now you edited the name of the file included into `main.c`. After the edit it is safe to assert that most of the symptoms you describe ***are not possble*** with the current versions of the files. Re-verify what you are doing, post updated disgnostic information and/or post real code.

Still, you compiler and linker lines are referring to old file names.

Answer (score 0):

i donno whats causing this , but i had this problem just now . 
try to delete the .h file and put the declarations of the functions on the top of .c file itself .

in this case , delete the test1.h and put the declarations of functions of test1.c in test1.c.
and include test1.c in test.c 
you wont get that warning message any more , nor the following linking errors .